# Product Repository Shows 'Requested product doesn't exist' After Setting is_in_stock = 0

Tags: magento2, stock

I Have Loaded A Simple Product Using 
`Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository` And Changed Its Quantity To 1 And Stock Status (`is_in_stock`) To `0`,

Using Function `$productStock->setQuantityAndStockStatus(['qty' => $correctedStock, 'is_in_stock' => $isInStock]);`

After This Am Not Able To Load The Product Programmatically , It Shows Following Error.

> `1 exception(s):
>   Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): Requested product doesn't exist

Using Magento CE 2.1.2

Comment: I think you miss some settings . 1st check is your product enable or not.

Comment: its enabled, i have checked.

Comment: after setting is_in_status = 0 , product will be disabled automatically ?

Comment: set is_in_stock to 1 .  I think 0 means out of stock

Comment: Yah , I Want To make It out of stock , and set qty 1 because of some m2 bug

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin > Stores > configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Stock Options

Set **Display Out of Stock Products** to **NO**

Answer (score 0):

You can  create a Helper class (as given below ) to update product inventory as you want .

Assume you are using a custom extension **Company_MyModule**

```
<?php
namespace Company\MyModule\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{

    /**
     * @var Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $_productRepository;

    /**
     * @var Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface 
     */
    protected $_stockStateInterface;

    /**
     * @var Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface 
     */
    protected $_stockRegistry;



    /**
    * @param Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
    * @param Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
    * @param Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface $stockStateInterface,
    * @param Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
    */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface $stockStateInterface,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry    
    ) {
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->_stockStateInterface = $stockStateInterface;
        $this->_stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;        
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * For Update stock of product
     * @param int $productId which stock you want to update
     * @param array $stockData your updated data
     * @return void 
    */
    public function updateProductStock($productId,$stockData) {
        $product = $this->_productRepository->getById($productId); //load product which you want to update stock
        $productSku = $product->getSku();
        $stockItem = $this->_stockRegistry->getStockItemBySku($productSku); // load stock of that product  by SKU                                       
        $stockItem->setIsInStock($stockData['is_in_stock']); //set updated data as your requirement
        $stockItem->setQty($stockData['qty']); //set updated quantity 
        $stockItem->setManageStock($stockData['manage_stock']);  
        $this->_stockRegistry->updateStockItemBySku($productSku,$stockItem);        
    }
}
```